# Hide a row in Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder 2012 3.0 based on an expression

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

### Employee ##   ## Worked Hours

```
  1                 40
  2                 40
  3                 24
  4                  0
  5                 40
```

So I made this summary in `Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder 2012 3.0.` Now I want to run this report but when I run it, it should not show the rows where the 'Worked Hours' are equal to `40`. I tried to base the row visibility on an `IIf-expression` but it always gives me an error.

This is the expression I used: = `IIf(Fields!TotalHours.Value<>40, 1,0)`

Is there anyone around here? who can give me the correct answer?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Do you have a place to put a filter in there?

Comment: The error that I get is the following: _The Hidden expression used in tablix ‘Details’ returned a data type that is not valid. (rsInvalidExpressionDataType)_

Comment: Hi Sagi, I don't know what you mean with a place to put a filter in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried as below in `Show or Hide Based on Expression` option ?

```
=IIF( Fields!TotalHours.Value = 40, True, False )
```

Comment: Awesome! I used this expression _=Iif( Fields!TotalHours.Value = 40, True, False )_ and now I have what I wanted. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note that this could be written just as =Fields!TotalHours.Value=40.   =IIF(...,TRUE,FALSE) is redundant.